# http.DetectContentType() support .xlxs？

Tags: go

How do I use the DetectContentType method to tell if a file is a.xlxs file? Through the search data found that the.xlxs file header description seems to be the same to the first 4 bytes, how do I judge?

Hope to be able to support, if not, what can be done to solve the problem?

Comment: This is basically impossible. xlxs files are technically zip files and you would have to inspect the content. Find some other (reliable) way to know the content type.